# Summation under Zeckendorf Representation

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci, bitwise, integer

[Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) shows that every positive integer can be uniquely represented as a sum of non-adjacent Fibonacci numbers. In this challenge, you have to compute the sum of two numbers in Zeckendorf representation.

---

Let F<sub>n</sub> be the *n*-th Fibonacci number where

> F<sub>1</sub> = 1,
>   F<sub>2</sub> = 2  and
>   for all *k* > 2, F<sub>*k*</sub> = F<sub>*k* - 1</sub> + F<sub>*k* - 2</sub>.

The *Zeckendorf representation* Z(*n*) of a non-negative integer *n* is a set of positive integers such that

> *n* = Σ<sub>*i* ∈ Z(*n*)</sub> F<sub>*i*</sub>  and
>   ∀<sub>*i* ∈ Z(*n*)</sub> *i* + 1 ∉ Z(*n*).

(in prosa: the Zeckendorf representation of a number *n* is a set of positive integers such that the Fibonacci numbers for these indices sum up to *n* and no two adjacent integers are part of that set)

Notably, the Zeckendorf representation is unique. Here are some examples for Zeckendorf representations:

> Z(0) = ∅ (the empty set)
>   Z(1) = {1}
>   Z(2) = {2}
>   Z(3) = {3} ({1, 2} is not the Zeckendorf representation of 3)
>   Z(10) = {5, 2}
>   Z(100) = {3, 5, 10}

In this challenge, Zeckendorf representations are encoded as [bit sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) where the least significant bit represents if `1` is part of the set, etc. You may assume that the Zeckendorf representations of both input and output fit into 31 bits.

Your task is to compute Z(*n* + *m*) given Z(*n*) and Z(*m*). The solution with the shortest length in octets wins.

You can find a reference implementation written in ANSI C [here](http://fuz.su/~fuz/src/zeck.c). It can also be used to generate Zeckendorf representations or compute a number from its Zeckendorf representation.

Here are some pairs of sample input and output, where the first two columns contain the input and the third column contains the output:

```
73865           9077257         9478805
139808          287648018       287965250
34              279004309       279004425
139940          68437025        69241105
272794768       1051152         273846948
16405           78284865        83888256
9576577         4718601         19013770
269128740       591914          270574722
8410276         2768969         11184785
16384           340             16724
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the Input/Output?

Comment: @flawr Please have a look at the provided reference implementation. You can use it to generate your own sample input.

Comment: I'd be happy if you could document here exactly what you want and provide some examples, as I am, and perhaps others are too, not fluent in C.

Comment: I disagree with the uniqueness argument. Since the Fibonacci sequence starts with 1, 1, 2 you can clearly decompose 3 into F0 + F2 = 1 + 2 = 3. F0 and F2 are _not_ adjacent.

Comment: @orlp The Fibonacci sequence defined here starts with F1=1 and F2=2. So the way I read it, F0 from your definition is not part of the sequence used here.

Comment: @RetoKoradi F(0) follows from the formula F(k) = F(k - 1) + F(k - 2) when evaluating for k = 2. If the sequence doesn't start with 1 1 2, then the sequence isn't the Fibonacci sequence anyway.

Comment: @orlp The Fibonacci numbers with indices smaller than 1 are not considered in this representation.

Comment: @flawr Let me add some test cases just for you.

Comment: @orlp Compare the sentence “The Zeckendorf representation Z(n) of a non-negative integer n is a set of *positive integers* such that...”

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't understand. Either your sequence starts with 1, 1, 2, or you shouldn't call it the Fibonacci sequence. A sequence that starts with 1, 2 is similar to the Fibonacci sequence, but not actually the sequence itself. I would be ok with 'any number bigger than 3 has a unique representation', but I do not agree with calling this a result over the Fibonacci sequence, when it is clearly not. In fact, in my example above F(0) is an abomination. By definition F(1) = 1 and F(2) = 1 for the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @orlp The series does “start” with 1, 1, just at different indices which are not considered for the Zeckendorf representation.

Comment: @FUZxxl A core property of the Fibonacci sequence is that F(n) = (phi^n - (1 - phi)^n) / sqrt(5). This property fails for your sequence, because it is not the Fibonacci sequence. The indices matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>45 43 42</s> 41 bytes

```
{2/<':(+/F@&+/'|2\x){y!x}\|F:64(+':1,)/0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/NTgJRDIX3PsU1MQJBM21vb3@mLlzxEkCCmzEGgwlhMZMBX328QNyd9PScft2/Hj4P09S1IzVvs3a@bFbvz8tmdqZNvxiHx/6yOa9a4fly1uLLooHLdGrHp/Xwe2y71MfuZx/zXffx9R19DHFcbC8Pp7Vmk5IcVKloOKsZlG01MLuBJTIVNkCLqlwKFbi6mROpA3AGj7ti@s85QxLjrEAlxIkR752kdZVVLNUBYqEazcbibLeoMJSkRsYVKiybGRW5Wl5UimpiRRPAQAfMqjcWEscKV48WR0eupVCUlejqGiOQSsUVc/FARKtf3lmlXk@ZIVCUeDv9AQ)

[@Bubbler's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54287/summation-under-zeckendorf-representation/196175#196175)

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`64(` `)/0` do 64 times, using 0 as initial value:

- `1,` prepend 1
- `+':` add each prior (leave the first element intact)

`F:` assign to `F` for "fibonacci sequence"

`|` reverse

`(`..`){y!x}\`.. starting with the value on the left, compute cumulative remainders (left-to-right) for the list on the right. the value on the left is the plain sum of the inputs without zeckendorf representation:

- `2\x` binary encode the inputs. this will be an nbits-by-2 matrix
- `|` reverse
- `+/'` sum each
- `&` where are the 1s? - list of indices. if there are any 2s, the corresponding index is repeated twice.
- `F@` array indexing into `F`
- `+/` sum

`<':` less than each prior (the first of the result will always be falsey)

`2/` binary decode

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 39 bytes

```apl
⊥1↓⍧|/⌽(+/g[⍸⌽+/⊤⎕]),↑,\⌽g←(2+/,)⍣38⍨⍳2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY89TgNBDIX7OcWUiZJobY/H9hyBigMARaT8NBGkoACJOqCIRSBESQUIehoaLjMXWYzYpbP93vfmzXy7mS0u55uz9Wx5cb48XSwXXb17Ojisu3sI9eZ61dX9G9bdY23fr5p6@z2aNOuj2n75OGnq/tXdJ@Np3T1Mj/20dm5Ek2Y6ru1Lstp@1PaTOg/qVrG2z7GwmkEOmkxyLKBKWcOfRqZFMmUImIqB/R6EDdAGgxYAZsohcb8kKL0ohRjRox0uDFGMk4J7BzYZS2ELpI6yikV3I2bqHZbMjLIEFIYc1cjYS/YqFsCkCqFklawaWdEE8D8esrISBZKCXtwb5IIFeeARzf@egzECqTghVmRoj6LE/rKXjInhBw)

Changed into a full program taking one argument of length 2, and also changed the Fibonacci generator. Thanks to @ngn for lots of ideas.

Uses `⎕IO←0` so that `⍳2` evaluates to `0 1`.

#### Fibonacci generator (new)

Note that the last two numbers are inaccurate, but it doesn't change the output of the program.

```apl
(2+/,)⍣38⍨⍳2
→ 0 1 ((2+/,)⍣38) 0 1

Step 1
0 1 (2+/,) 0 1
→ 2+/ 0 1 0 1
→ (0+1) (1+0) (0+1) ⍝ 2+/ evaluates sums for moving window of length 2
→ 1 1 1

Step 2
0 1 (2+/,) 1 1 1
→ 2+/ 0 1 1 1 1
→ 1 2 2 2

Step 3
0 1 (2+/,) 1 2 2 2
→ 2+/ 0 1 1 2 2 2
→ 1 2 3 4 4
```

#### Zeckendorf to plain (partial)

```apl
⍸⌽+/⊤⎕
     ⎕  ⍝ Take input from stdin, must be an array of 2 numbers
    ⊤   ⍝ Convert each number to base 2; each number is mapped to a column
  +/    ⍝ Sum in row direction; add up the counts at each digit position
 ⌽      ⍝ Reverse
⍸       ⍝ Convert each number n at index i to n copies of i
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 47 bytes

```apl
g←1↓(1,+\⍤,)⍣20⍨1
{⊥1↓⍧|/⌽⍵,↑,\⌽g}+⍥{+/g[⍸⌽⊤⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY8xTgMxEEV7n2JLUDbKjD32jAsqGlIhETpCESnJNhFQUIBCKqQUEY5AiBOQCDoqJBoajuKLLONtLHue//fz5GbRn95PFtdNf3Z3O7uazqZt2@T1M@b16wHWvXFOu/owp3cLOX2iWebNvrCcPh4G@ek3p@86r1/qse6bVS@n/bI3aC5y@ilws1N@uWrn2pjTNm/fhqd58/j35TSjp9HZsa7nJ8NRG4lFwFdHFTsJvppXEZitZ2OFY/DWgzJ0UUAU6jCQAIqxHAGIbIk6KqgbOIgmREuIXakGI4HSIOQYrNecEwqRRKllDRGH0qz3Eb014kTE@lDCgaAYsVghlTMYAR1zMYqeg2dWSowSALUYPBNbW4pDRFXtXvYRI5JBRNG/FikhBMuhcw4SQzQY2FL3osrp3BH8Aw)

Changed Part 1 of the previous answer to reuse the Fibonacci numbers. Also, drop the duplicate 1 to save some bytes in other places.

#### Part 1 (new)

```apl
{+/g[⍸⌽⊤⍵]}
       ⊤⍵    ⍝ Argument to binary digits
     ⍸⌽      ⍝ Reverse and convert to indices of ones
   g[    ]   ⍝ Index into the Fibonacci array of 1,2,3,5,...
 +/          ⍝ Sum
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 52 bytes

```apl
{⊥1↓¯1↓⍧|/⌽⍵,↑,\⌽(1,+\⍤,)⍣20⍨1}+⍥({+∘÷⍣(⌽⍳≢⊤⍵)⍨1}⊥⊤)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY@xSgNBEIb7e4orE5LgzO7szmxhZWMqwVimCSTaBLWwUKKVEDR4QRHBWhO0SyFiZRPfZF7knL1m2Jl//n@@HZ1Pe@Or0fTspDe5vJicjifjup7pYo06f95uctXq43pHH361@u7q/Kk7tHcLu52hVqtuW6t3B1p94k1Hq3Vr1tG7178fm7Yay5fev@liZd52s2TJ1rbrY50/arXU5Uv/QBe32423aOsGh3tWj/b7gzoRi0Aod0v2EkN5XCZgdoELJ5xicAFMQ58ExEQbRhJAKRwnACKXrZ6y1Aw8pCImR4hNqBkTgalRyDO4YD4vFBOJqY7NRBxzsu0jBleIFxEXYjZHgkzE4oQMrsAE6JkzUQocA7OpxCgR0IIhMLFzOTgmNNTmckiYkApEFPtrhhJCcBwb5igppgIjO2ouGpzNPcE/)

#### How it works

No fancy algorithm to do addition in Zeckendorf because APL isn't known for operation on individual elements in an array. Instead, I went ahead to convert the two inputs from Zeckendorf to plain integers, add them, and convert it back.

#### Part 1: Zeckendorf to plain integer

```apl
{+∘÷⍣(⌽⍳≢⊤⍵)⍨1}⊥⊤  ⍝ Zeckendorf to plain integer
                ⊤  ⍝ Convert the input to array of binary digits (X)
{    (  ≢⊤⍵)  }    ⍝ Take the length L of the binary digits and
      ⌽⍳           ⍝   generate 1,2..L backwards, so L..2,1
{+∘÷⍣(     )⍨1}    ⍝ Apply "Inverse and add 1" L..2,1 times to 1
                   ⍝ The result looks like ..8÷5 5÷3 3÷2 2 (Y)
               ⊥   ⍝ Mixed base conversion of X into base Y

Base |             Digit value
-------------------------------
13÷8 | (8÷5)×(5÷3)×(3÷2)×2 = 8
 8÷5 |       (5÷3)×(3÷2)×2 = 5
 5÷3 |             (3÷2)×2 = 3
 3÷2 |                   2 = 2
 2÷1 |                   1 = 1
```

#### Part 2: Add two plain integers

```apl
+⍥z2i  ⍝ Given left and right arguments,
       ⍝   apply z2i to each of them and add the two
```

#### Part 3: Convert the sum back to Zeckendorf

"You may assume that the Zeckendorf representations of both input and output fit into 31 bits" was pretty handy.

```apl
{⊥1↓¯1↓⍧|/⌽⍵,↑,\⌽(1,+\⍤,)⍣20⍨1}  ⍝ Convert plain integer N to Zeckendorf
                 (1,+\⍤,)⍣20⍨1   ⍝ First 41 Fibonacci numbers starting with two 1's
                ⌽                ⍝ Reverse
             ↑,\                 ⍝ Matrix of prefixes, filling empty spaces with 0's
          ⌽⍵,                    ⍝ Prepend N to each row and reverse horizontally
        |/                       ⍝ Reduce by | (residue) on each row (see below)
       ⍧                         ⍝ Nub sieve; 1 at first appearance of each number, 0 otherwise
  1↓¯1↓                          ⍝ Remove first and last item
 ⊥                               ⍝ Convert from binary digits to integer
```

#### The Fibonacci generator

```apl
(1,+\⍤,)⍣20⍨1
→ 1 ((1,+\⍤,)⍣20) 1  ⍝ Expand ⍨
→ Apply 1 (1,+\⍤,) x 20 times to 1

First iteration
1(1,+\⍤,)1
→ 1,+\1,1  ⍝ Expand the train
→ 1,1 2    ⍝ +\ is cumulative sum
→ 1 1 2    ⍝ First three Fibonacci numbers

Second iteration
1(1,+\⍤,)1 1 2
→ 1,+\1,1 1 2  ⍝ Expand the train
→ 1 1 2 3 5    ⍝ First five Fibonacci numbers

⍣20  ⍝ ... Repeat 20 times
```

This follows from the property of Fibonacci numbers: if Fibonacci is defined as

$$
F_0 = F_1 = 1; \forall n \ge 0, F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n
$$

then

$$
\forall n \ge 0, \sum_{i=0}^{n} F_i = F_{n+2} - 1
$$

So cumulative sum of \$ 1,F_0, \cdots, F_n \$ (Fibonacci array prepended with a 1) becomes \$ F_1, \cdots, F_{n+2} \$. Then I prepend a 1 again to get the usual Fibonacci array starting with index 0.

#### Fibonacci to Zeckendorf digits

```apl
Input: 7, Fibonacci: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13

Matrix
0 0 0 0 0 0 13 7
0 0 0 0 0 8 13 7
0 0 0 0 5 8 13 7
0 0 0 3 5 8 13 7
0 0 2 3 5 8 13 7
0 1 2 3 5 8 13 7
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 7

Reduction by residue (|/)
- Right side always binds first.
- x|y is equivalent to y%x in other languages.
- 0|y is defined as y, so leading zeros are ignored.
- So we're effectively doing cumulative scan from the right.
0 0 0 0 0 0 13 7 → 13|7 = 7
0 0 0 0 0 8 13 7 →  8|7 = 7
0 0 0 0 5 8 13 7 →  5|7 = 2
0 0 0 3 5 8 13 7 →  3|2 = 2
0 0 2 3 5 8 13 7 →  2|2 = 0
0 1 2 3 5 8 13 7 →  1|0 = 0
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 7 →  1|0 = 0
Result: 7 7 2 2 0 0 0

Nub sieve (⍧): 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
1's in the middle are produced when divisor ≤ dividend
(so it contributes to a Zeckendorf digit).
But the first 1 and last 0 are meaningless.

Drop first and last (1↓¯1↓): 0 1 0 1 0
Finally, we apply base 2 to integer (⊥) to match the output format.
```

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, <s>76</s> <s>74</s> <s>70</s> <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```
2q~{32{2\#I&},}fI+32_,*{WUer$Kf-[UU]/[-2X]*2,/2a*Kf+}fKf#1b
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2q~%7B32%7B2%5C%23I%26%7D%2C%7DfI%2B32_%2C*%7BWUer%24Kf-%5BUU%5D%2F%5B-2X%5D*2%2C%2F2a*Kf%2B%7DfKf%231b&input=%5B73865%209077257%5D) or [verify all test cases at once](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%5B~%5D)2%40%7B32%7B2%5C%23I%26%7D%2C%7DfI%2B32_%2C*%7BWUer%24Kf-%5BUU%5D%2F%5B-2X%5D*2%2C%2F2a*Kf%2B%7DfKf%231b%3Dp%7D%2F&input=73865%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%209077257%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%209478805%0A139808%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20287648018%20%20%20%20%20%20%20287965250%0A34%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20279004309%20%20%20%20%20%20%20279004425%0A139940%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2068437025%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2069241105%0A272794768%20%20%20%20%20%20%201051152%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20273846948%0A16405%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2078284865%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2083888256%0A9576577%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%204718601%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2019013770%0A269128740%20%20%20%20%20%20%20591914%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20270574722%0A8410276%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%202768969%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2011184785%0A16384%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20340%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2016724).

#### Idea

We start by defining a minor variation of the sequence in the question:

> **G<sub>-2</sub> = 0**
>   **G<sub>-1</sub> = 1**
>   **G<sub>k</sub> = G<sub>k-1</sub> + G<sub>k-2</sub>** whenever **k** is a non-negative integer

This way, the bit **0** (LSB) of the bit arrays input or output corresponds to the Fibonacci number **G<sub>0</sub>** and, in general, the bit **k** to **G<sub>k</sub>**.

Now, we replace each set bit in **Z(n)** and **Z(m)** by the index it encodes.

For example, the input **532<sub>10</sub> = 1000010100<sub>2</sub>** gets transformed into **[2 4 9]**.

This yields two arrays of integers, which we can concatenate to form a single one.

For example, if **n = m = 100**, the result is **A := [2 4 9 2 4 9]**.

If we replace each **k** in **A** by **G<sub>k</sub>** and add the results, we obtain **n + m = 200**, so **A** is *a* way to decompose **200** into Fibonacci numbers, but certainly not the one from Zeckendorf's theorem.

Keeping in mind that **G<sub>k</sub> + G<sub>k+1</sub> = G<sub>k+2</sub>** and **G<sub>k</sub> + G<sub>k</sub> = G<sub>k</sub> + G<sub>k-1</sub> + G<sub>k-2</sub> = G<sub>k+1</sub> + G<sub>k-2</sub>**, we can substitute consecutive and duplicated indexes by others (namely, **(k, k + 1)** by **k + 2** and **(k, k)** by **(k + 1, k - 2)**), repeating those substitutions over and over until the Zeckendorf representation is reached.<sup>1</sup>

Special case has to be taken for resulting negative indexes. Since **G<sub>-2</sub> = 0**, index **-2** can simply be ignored. Also, **G<sub>-1</sub> = 0 = G<sub>0</sub>**, so any resulting **-1** has to be replaced by **0**.

For our example **A**, we obtain the following (sorted) representations, the last being the Zeckendorf representation.

**[2 2 4 4 9 9] → [0 3 4 4 9 9] → [0 5 4 9 9] → [0 6 9 9] → [0 6 7 10] → [0 8 10]**

Finally, we convert back from array of integers to bit array.

#### Code

```
2             e# Push a 2 we'll need later.
q~            e# Read and evaluate the input.
{             e# For each integer I in the input:
  32{         e#   Filter [0 ... 31]; for each J:
    2\#       e#     Compute 2**J.
    I&        e#     Compute its logical AND with I.
  },          e#   Keep J if the result in truthy (non-zero).
}fI           e#
+             e# Concatenate the resulting arrays.
32_,*         e# Repeat [0 ... 31] 32 times.
{             e# For each K:
  WUer        e#   Replace -1's with 0's.
  $           e#   Sort.
  Kf-         e#   Subtract K from each element.
  [UU]/[-2X]* e#   Replace subarrays [0 0] with [-2 1].
  2,/2a*      e#   Replace subarrays [0 1] with [2].
  Kf+         e#   Add K to each element.
}fK           e#
f#            e# Replace each K with 2**K.
1b            e# Cast all to integer (discards 2**-2) and sum.
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The implementation attempts substituting 32 times and does not check if the Zeckendorf representation has in fact been reached. I do not have a formal proof that this is sufficient, but I've tested all possible sums of 15-bit representations (whose sums' representations require up to 17 bits) and 6 repetitions was enough for all of them. In any case, augmenting the number of repetitions to 99 is possible without incrementing the byte count, but it would cripple performance.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 325 <del>396</del> bytes

EDIT: new version:

```
s f[]=[]
s f l=f l
x((a:b):(c:d):(e:r))=x(b:d:(a:e):r)
x(a:b:((c:d:e):r))=x((c:a):b:e:((d:s head r):s tail r))
x[]=[]
x(a:r)=a:x r
w l|x l/=l=w.x$l|True=l
l=length
t n x=take n$repeat x
j 0=[]
j n=t(mod(n)2)1:j(div(n)2)
i n=[[],[]]++j n++t(32-(l$j n))[]
u[]=0
u(a:r)=2*u r+l a
o(_:a:r)=u r+l a
z a b=o$w$zipWith(++)(i a)(i b)
```

`z` does the job.

Comment: Some stuff can get shortened straight away - for example function has the highest precedence, so you can gut rid of parents around function applications, and also guards don't need parents either - guards stop where the `=` is, so parents there aren't needed, and so on and so forth, and note that `:` associates to the right and you can cut some there.                     But, anyways, congrats! Looks greatly complicated. Can't wait to figure out how this works!

Comment: @proudhaskeller Uselessly complicated, though, see my edit. Shall I explain the basic idea? It might be better another way, but I tried to do as much pattern matching as possible at first. Ah, by parents you mean parentheses: golf'd that!

Comment: chillax, it's on of your first times here. If you stay long, you will grow much better. Be sure to check the Haskell golfing tips question for some insight http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell

Comment: @proudhaskeller edit arrived...

Answer (score 4):

### ES6, 130 bytes

```
(n,m)=>{for(a={},s=0,i=x=y=1;i<<1;i+=i,z=y,y=x,x+=z)s+=((n&i)+(m&i))/i*(a[i]=x);for(r=0;i;i>>>=1)s>=a[i]?(s-=a[i],r|=i):0;return r}
```

I originally tried to compute the sum in-place (effectively along the lines of the CJam implementation) but I kept running out of temporaries, so I just converted the numbers to and back from real integers.

(Yes, I can probably save a byte by using eval.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>85 73</s> 65 bytes

```ruby
->*a{r=(0..2*a.sum).select{|r|r^r*2==r*3};r[a.sum{|w|r.index w}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104rsbrIVsNAT89IK1GvuDRXU684NSc1uaS6pqimKK5Iy8jWtkjLuNa6KBosXV1TXlOkl5mXklqhUF4bW/u/QCEt2tDM2MJEx9jEIJYLxDU3tjAz1VGwNDA3NzI1j/0PAA)

#### How?

First get an upper bound for the encoded sum: (a+b)*2 is ok.

Now filter out all non-zeckendorf numbers from (0..limit).

We have a lookup table, it's downhill from here.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 207 bytes

```
def s(n):
 p=1
 while n>=2*p:
  p*=2
 return n if n<=p else s(n+p//2)if n>=3*p/2 else s(m)if (m:=s(n-p)+p)!= n else n
a=lambda n,m:(b:=n&m)>-1 and s(a(a(a(s((n|m)-b%4),b//4*2),b//4),b%4*2+b%4//2))if m else n
```

[Try it Online! (Verify all test cases)](https://tio.run/##NY/tboMgFIZ/16tgJl2g4uT7wwxvpOkPTW1qUilRl3XJ7t2B7SCBw3Pe97wh/CzXu@cmTOt67i9ghh7V2S44mu2@r8OtB75x7BAi24WDY9lu6pevyQMPhgvwny6A/jb3yVeEqmIo0cbxQ6jYf2dMEI61i6IyoCKgNxf9W9dnrbu1Y3dugcdjDbva@fcRNSUFrT9Hc7vtGUL/O6Ky2wuEu6oSB/a847mPjyKeKT0lja/J69LPy@yOueZGSWyJ1kzqHGc55dYQg5nRShhCTWJcYKYtIYIT@9JYQbAygmvCZEJMR4XQymBKJKWSbToliMTaMCNiSiJWaiW1xkJTowjdnMrSmBbnSUstFYkZQQnTKqYqY9UzU3EjMBckP2XZ5T6BAQwebN@oMxDXww0fc7gNC8xxjjYUpsEv8HEkpyIyDB5HesIgL5tYt/C/h/CzoieE0PoH)

### Explanation

This program directly manipulates the binary translations of the Zeckendorf representations. The function `a(n,m)` performs the main calculations, and `s(n)` is a helper function that gets rid of adjacent numbers contained in the Zeckendorf representation.

Let's start with the function `s(n)` (expanded for clarity):

```
def s(n): 
    p=1                  #This finds the highest digit of the binary form of n.
    while n>=2*p:
        p*=2
    if n<=p:             #If n is a power of two (i.e, our number is already a Fibonnaci number)...
        return n         #Then return it normally.  This also works for zero. (A)
    if n>=3*p/2:         #If n's first digit is followed by a 1 (i.e, it starts with 11X)
        return s(n+p//2) #Then replace that with 100X (B)
    m = s(n-p)+p         #Otherwise, apply s to the rest of the number (C)
    if m==n:             #If this is out final result, we're done! (D)
        return n
    return s(m)          #Otherwise, reapply it. (E)
```

For example, the number 107 (`1101011` in binary, representing 1+2+5+13+21=42), undergoes the following process:

```
1+2+5+13+21 [1101011] -> 1+2+5+34 [10001011] (B)
1+2+5+34 [10001011] (C)
 1+2+5 [1011] (C)
  1+2 [11] -> 3 [100] (B)
 ->3+5 [1100] (A/E)
 (E):  3+5 [1100] -> 8 [10000] (B)
->8+34 [10010000] (A/E)
(E): 8+34 [10010000] (C)
->8+34 [10010000] (A/E)
```

[Try it Online!  (s with detailed output)](https://tio.run/##fVTBjpswEL3zFVNX1eJASGAPrVAdadum0p566S3aA1mcxaqxLeMIpT@fjoEAyUa1IgXGnnnz3jxjTq7S6vGLsedzyQ9wEPtQ0TwAXOIAirEUtPX/WR/0y3J3tApUMHvpEpcpjfqHjAaBr2f5Qdu6cGNRfXTm6BghPQQwSLunmvXl2kpIDmqznuB8H58y7GQKTZUi1jgbelBBaUQiMqVFLB1fFFOrVTZvuE/f5cv0JSKwIxDBXqiwprssx8gL6Qk0oYolW9McumSDetxZH39XokENVNmAqzhU4q3ijYNSvAkH@tAFsXxhT@AF8SGVXBFm2cJMBM2CZeMQvjKT3wI@YxwQswCjW247jFZDKBIeIzcc2bHeY9wfkZYX5QmP/hR7rVTxKoZdmiTJu6le0@LqsoFElJ@llKcEoCNcyEZDq@2fxrOCv9zqBMInOna@YY8Ls8ry284fvFh2FMhrp6VEIiXsfaPpQAT3GldY10ArXAVpig3TSSQrlAsJkIWMZkbDcS43QGahyODwaQQEwm@U0FvKzXAilnSkbGTxynFshRug12vE9vnB/6HD7xeEGs2NpZcmlhFeDHMR4BeawbaiQX6FMfIE6BndOcR6zwxuGeaH5d4BkuVmxq7uUJ9W2wsuCl8zpu5Zxvmp4c8bBN1aSA95lC6Glj9YDqVW/AOEP@j9u37VRLjFS0Fi4KrE60yDK0Frr@UEPaOMXuxIC4dqbvEz0YTp@jM9n/8B)

Here is an expanded version of `a(n,m)`:

```
def a(n,m):
    if m==0:
        return n
    b=n&m
    t=s((n|m)-b%4)              #(A)
    t=a(t,b//4*2)               #(B)
    t=a(t,b//4)                 #(C)
    return s(a(t,b%4*2+b%4//2)) #(D)
```

This function converts the two Zeckendorf representations into four  binary numbers which are easier to combine.  Line (A) is the bitwise OR of the two binary Zeckendorf representations--these correspond to one copy of each Fibonacci number in either group. (B) and (C) are the bitwise AND of the two numbers right-shifted 1 and 2 times, respectively. We know that when the corresponding Fibonacci numbers for (B) and (C) are added together, they will be equivalent to the bitwise AND of our `n` and `m` because  F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2).

For example, let's say that we have the binary numbers n=101001 (corresponding to 1+5+13) and m=110110 (2+3+8+13).  Then we will have (A)=111111 (1+2+3+5+8+13), which is converted to 1010100 (3+8+21) by our function `s`, (B)=10000 (8), and (C)=1000 (5).  We can check that (1+5+13)+(2+3+8+13)=(3+8+21)+(8)+(5)=45.  This process repeats with ((3+8+21)+(8))+(5)=((3+8+21)+(5)+(3))+(5), etc.

The one difficulty with this system is that it doesn't work for the Fibonacci numbers 1 and 2, since they don't obey the property `F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)` (they're the lowest two numbers)!  Because of that, whenever 1 or 2 is contained in both `n` and `m`, they are removed from A, B, and C, then their sum placed in D under the property that 1+1=2 and 2+2=1+3.  For example, if we add 1+3 (101) + 1+3+5 (1101), we get:

(A): 3+5 (1100) = 8 (10000)

(B): 2 (10)

(C): 1 (1)

(D): 2 (10)

Notice that the 3 and 5 were placed into A, the duplicate 3 was split into 2+1 in B and C, and duplicate 1s were removed from A, B, and C, added together, and put into D.  Similarly, if we add 2+3 (110) + 2+3+5 (1110), we get:

(A): 3+5 (1100) = 8 (10000)

(B): 2 (10)

(C): 1 (1)

(D): 1+3 (101)

[Try it online! (a with detailed output)](https://tio.run/##fVNRb5swEH7Pr7gxdcWBkECraUJzpbVVpT3tZW9RH0zjFGvGtoxTlGn/PTvjJJAmG4oCHN/dfd99Z7N1tVY3X4zd7VZ8DWtRxYqUE8BLrEFRmoO2/l6EoL8sdxurQE1GL33iLCdJeCjIZOLrWb7WtmHuWFRvnNk4GkWhBVDI@6eGhnJdLSQHdbcY2nkeVwUyGUJDpYS2zsa@qSAkiZJoSEtofnxRVM3nxZhwSF@Ws/w5iWAZQQKVUHFDlkWJkecoCGhjlUq6ICX0yQbncXZ9/FmLFiegVi24mkMtXmveOliJV@FAr/sgFmd2C34cPqSyE7m0mJpBnpnS4mjBV2rK03bfMQrYkYHRHbd9h05DLDKeoi60a9NUGPcQaTlbbRH6JCqtFHsR@68ky7IzR8eSuDqEUYTyLkq5zQB6sUy2Gjptf7VeEfzmVmdHxnf0ZmrmRXnK@NqPyB7H4iempUQBK6g8wXwvAL@1jlnXQidcDXmORMl7pmhLYtDRVJIjVyPZC8dZM7fPXCwOGhvcM0yZmVQmuKNmYPYDvbGdaLExM0ZuAS3UvWHWW7g3L4zsILChVJ1b4vxc8OcNwF1g0lfYSJdCx68th5VW/MN/z1AbN17PRXJoY09PuCwsJsPFbMJqjngt/nFKK6o@NWGDrVAO4giiqUxGxzPxJyAaIg1GZrO7iJxnRfE3UkbpcLjbOFZ/GjKrrm4JQUPw@6Ws@9Osaj6/nRY9/v4i/uEc36MfLqIf36GvsHiC/7glfdZjyHJ0xBbXoSDvDvOBvKMsdmkgeQE3sB6Al2AwEH7D1j10RK1PGek5yPGjH8x420P2nr4FORMWf07zW7Lb/QU)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 218 bytes

```
Fold[#+##&,Total@PadLeft@IntegerDigits[#,2]//.{{p=n_/;n>1,r=y___}:>{0,n,y},{q=x___,i_,p,j_,k_,r}:>{x,i+1,n-2,j,k+1,y},{q,i_,p,j_}:>{x,i+1,n-2,j+1},{q,i_,p}:>{x,i+1,n-2},{1,1,r}:>{1,0,0,y},{q,i_,1,1,r}:>{x,i+1,0,0,y}}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Na4NAEIb/yoKQSyZ1Zt3d2W0x5FAKhR5y6E1EpDGp@TCp9ZAg/na7xjaQspfleZ@Zdw5581kc8qb8yPu1iPuX436VBNMgmMD7scn3i2W@eivWzeK1aopNUT@Xm7L5TgKQaRg@tO0prrLwqZoT1PEly7Lucd4iVHDpoP2Kz55AmcEJthnsMqiH@AzllKCaSdjCzv@u6p/1T5jSLbxLPCWgcR8B@nfbcuOjPGZdOumXdVk1SSBmc7FOgjQVExEuRNtyZI0G4ZBZau5AtBQ5ixaEtGyURbIDjJQH7BBVhO7XcgpBGKsiRqkHJtkrio0fJtREWl5No9A3sJVW@a4BOc1GM4NQTNYgXYeNI1857NSOHKkBWkUo2QzdxjozNpvI@msihV3X/wA)

Simply pattern matching.

Ungolfed:

```
FromDigits[Total@PadLeft@IntegerDigits[#, 2] //.
   {{n_ /; n > 1, y___} :> {0, n, y},
    {x___, i_, n_ /; n > 1, j_, k_, y___} :> {x, i + 1, n - 2, j, k + 1, y},
    {x___, i_, n_ /; n > 1, j_} :> {x, i + 1, n - 2, j + 1},
    {x___, i_, n_ /; n > 1} :> {x, i + 1, n - 2},
    {1, 1, y___} :> {1, 0, 0, y},
    {x___, i_, 1, 1, y___} :> {x, i + 1, 0, 0, y}}, 2] &
```